# How do I prepare these react files for hosting?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've been ask to take on a react project by a client and I'm struggling to understand how to prepare the files for hosting. I've used npm / webpack before, and I can see in the package.json the following:

```
"main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --config server.config.js && webpack --mode development && nodemon server.js",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "start": "webpack --mode production --config server.config.js && node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

Also within the webpack.config.js file I have this:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
```

I've run 'npm run heroku-postbuild'. This has led to a dist folder that gets created, which I expected would create the necessary compiled files to host on the server, however when I look in that directory all I get is a single 'bundle.js' file along with fonts and image assets.

What's confusing me is that there are zero generated HTML files.

Since I've not hosted a react site before, I'm not sure if this is what should be expected and if so, how do I set up hosting for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, webpack does not create an index.html file for you. There are two main routes you can go:

1. Create your own `index.html` by hand, which loads your `bundle.js` with a `<script>` tag. Place this in a folder called `public` (or `static` -- the name isn't important), and then copy this into your `dist` folder at build time. This is easier in the short term.
2. Use the [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/), which will generate an `index.html` file for you automatically, as part of the webpack build process. This is probably easier in the long run.